# Detect whether size_t is builtin with g++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, g++, built-in, size-t

Mac OS/X declarations make use of the builtin `size_t` as in:

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

That makes `size_t` a type that's different from any other type (such as `unsigned long`). This is true on PPC and amd64.

When compiling with i386, we get the usual:

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

so that works as expected for the rest of my development. However, when `size_t` is defined with the internal type, I have to add a declaration to my class.

So I would need to know whether the class should have that definition. Something like this:

```
class my_class
{
    ...
    void func(unsigned long ul);
#if SIZE_T_BUILTIN
    void func(size_t s);
#endif
    ...
};
```

What would `SIZE_T_BUILTIN` be to properly detect that size_t is its own type?

At this time I only need that for g++.

Comment: Do you need the `unsigned long` overload?  If you accept many different numeric types, why not make the constructor a template?  Then you don't have to care what types are available.

Comment: That's not a constructor, but I suppose you mean something like `template<T> func(T v)`? I'm pretty sure I tried that and it wasn't working well when I did it (over 10 years ago). It could be that g++ 4.8+ would properly support that templating though.

Comment: You can't assume that `size_t` is typedef'ed as `unsigned long`; it could as easily be typedef'ed as `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`.

Comment: `__SIZE_TYPE__` is actually a predefined macro expanding to a built-in type, so even when `size_t` is defined as `__SIZE_TYPE__`, it's the same as one of the regular types. The standard requires `size_t` to be an integer type, and GCC explicitly documents that it does not support *any* extended integer types. From that, you can conclude that it will *always* be the same as one of the standard integer types.

Comment: @AlexisWilke My bad, I was coding a constructor at the time.  Guess something got mixed up in my head.  But yes, a template member could be the way to go -- and g++ should support that.  I have never had issues with g++ understanding template methods.

Comment: @hvd, and yet I can define both of those functions and compile them fine under Mac OS/X. However, under, say Linux, it fails compilation. What else could be happening? (i.e. I do have one func() per integer type, char, short, int, long, long long and unsigned of each plus signed char...) Could there be another integer type I do not know of? Also, if I don't define the size_t, I get the error saying that C++ cannot choose which function to use (under Mac OS/X).

Comment: @cdhowie, yeah... searching for g++ version around 2000, it was 2.95 or so. Thus, testing with a templated function would probably make sense in 2014... then whatever the type it should do as expected.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Most likely, `__SIZE_TYPE__` expands to `unsigned int` rather than `unsigned long`, at least on some of the systems that use it. And having separate overloads for `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting whether `size_t` is one of the types you know about, you could just define it if it isn't one of the types you already overload for, e.g.:

```
void func(unsigned long);
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<!std::is_same<size_t, unsigned long>::value
               && std::is_same<T, size_t>::value>::type func(T);
```

This can be done whether `func()` is a member or not. The main trick is to make the conditional overload a function template so you can use SFINAE to conditionally disable it.